# mysql - disk usage optimization

Tags: mysql

I have 23 tables on mysql db server. I heard that there is a big disk usage (3GB) in the db server, but when I executed the following sql to see what is taking most space, it doesn't look like it is taking 3GB.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, table_rows, data_length, index_length, 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024),2) "Size in MB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = "prod_schema";
```

Does anybody know why the data coming from the above sql is different from the actual space usage in db?

Or is there anything that is occupying the space in the db server?

I am not quite familiar with the details of disk usage of the db server.

Thanks.

Comment: the logs maybe, did you check?

Comment: The db prod system is not accessible to me. if the logs are full, is it ok/safe to delete these logs?

Comment: If you do that with the apache logs it would not work, but for mysql I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MyIsam table engine, then this is the disk space you are using.
BUT if you are using InnoDB then binlog and other log files might increase space utilization.

Plus if this "big disk usage (3GB)" was counted by simply looking at the total size of the  MySQL library then this also includes the server exec files and different database log files.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer for those who are facing the same issue. Your log files may be eating space. It is also good to check mysql data directory.

1. Check disk usage of mysql data directory:

   du -sh /var/lib/mysql/
2. Find the location of log files by searching following keywords in my.ini or my.cnf. Then check the size of these files:

   - log_error
   - slow_query_log, slow_query_log_file, and long_query_time
   - general_log, general_log_file

Resource: https://medium.com/@hkarakose/understanding-mysql-disk-usage-a6b873720c17